# Javascript - putting an object's member function in a standalone variable?

Tags: javascript, function, object, closures, member

I'm trying to put a member function from a specific object in a standalone variable, hoping to be able to call the function (on the original object) by simply using the new variable.

So something like this:

```js
var str = "abcdefgh";
var fn = str.indexOf;
console.log(fn("e")); // supposed to output 4
```

So `fn(x)` is supposed to do the same as `str.indexOf(x)`. But this doesn't work. Is there another way I can pull this off?

Note that the difficulty here is I want fn to call the function **on that specific `str` object**.
So `fn` is to become some sort of closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**You Don't Know JS Series**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md), JS determines the `this` in this way

1. Is the function called with new (new binding)? If so, this is the
   newly constructed object.

   `var bar = new foo()`
2. Is the function called with call or apply (explicit binding), even
   hidden inside a bind hard binding? If so, this is the explicitly
   specified object.

   `var bar = foo.call( obj2 )`
3. Is the function called with a context (implicit binding), otherwise
   known as an owning or containing object? If so, this is that context
   object.

   `var bar = obj1.foo()`
4. Otherwise, default the this (default binding). If in strict mode,
   pick undefined, otherwise pick the global object.

   `var bar = foo()`

**Your problem**

When you call the `indexOf` on the `str.indexOf('e')`, JS engine starts to lookup for the context in the function. It sees that you have called the function with `.` notation on a string object and refers the context to it. But 
when you get the reference of the function and tries to call like `fn`, engine starts to search the context (*mentioned above*) and didn't find anything. Otherwise when you get a function reference outside it loses it's context. So you need to give the context explicitly.

Here I write, that whenever the `fn` will be called, the `this` inside the function will refer to the `str` variable.

```js
var str = "abcdefgh";
var fn = str.indexOf.bind(str);
console.log(fn("e")); // supposed to output 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 variety javascript, you can use an "arrow function" to achieve this. It's a nice, short syntax.

```
var fn = () => str.indexOf("e");
```

For further reference,
[see the mozilla docs on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

This variable can of course be passed around. Note that with this solution, the variable fn holds a direct reference to the string that you are executing a function on, so it solves your context problem.

Comment: Nice! For compatibility reasons I'll prefer the `bind()` approach from above, but this is a great alternative. Thanks!